# Using promises and non promises in a chain

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I have a series of promises (mostly ajax calls but a few deffereds).

I call them like so, my question is I also need to mix in some standard functions that do not return promises, I have had a go below, is this the correct way to do it?

Basically i want promise A, B and C to run, then do my non promise methods, once these are done, carry on with promise D and E.

```
this.promiseA()
.then(this.promiseB)
.then(this.promiseC)
.then(function(){

    //do some methods that do not return promises
})
.then(this.promiseD)
.then(this.promiseE);
```

Comment: Are those properties of `this` actual promises, or do you mean functions that return promises? That's a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.promiseA()
.then(this.promiseB)
.then(this.promiseC)
.then(function(){

    //do some methods that do not return promises
    // modify original promise here , else original promise
    // passed to next `.then` in chain
    // return $.when(true); 
})
.then(this.promiseD)
.then(this.promiseE);
```

Comment: thanks, ive just tried it without your when and it still works, why?

Comment: @panthro `.then()` returns a new promise.

Comment: could you explain abit more

Comment: @panthro _"As of jQuery 1.8, the deferred.then() method returns a new promise that can filter the status and values of a deferred through a function,"_ http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then

Comment: but why does it still continue the chain, even without a when?

Comment: @panthro _"If the filter function used is null, or not specified, the promise will be resolved or rejected with the same values as the original."_ http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then . Can create stacksnippets http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: No there is no return between promise C and promiseD, not in any of the methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80073/discussion-between-guest271314-and-panthro).

Comment: @panthro See updated post. Commented out `return $.when(true)` as being necessary to continue chain

Answer (score 0):

`then` functions can send back anything, including undefined. This anything is encapsulated in a new Promise if needed so the chain can continue.

If your function returns a Promise or a thenable, the chain will continue when this object is fullfilled. `promiseD` will then receive the resolved value of this thenable.

If your function returns an immediate value or null or undefined, the chain will continue immediately. `promiseD` will receive said value.

So yes, your solution is correct.